# GoDaddy website wont print - GoDaddy admits this "feature", but has no fix

Tags: printing

I can't get my GoDaddy web site to print correctly.  Go Daddy acknowledges pages created/hosted with its website builder may print incorrectly or not at all.  (https://www.godaddy.com/help/print-site-pages-16526) My experience is I get a boxed image, and never more than one page, with vertical and horizontal scroll bars in it.

I have tried script solutions like "printfriendly" and "printwhatyoulike" and "URLtoPDF" and various screenshot scripts, but all deliver the same botched print job.  The results were the same across chrome, explorer and safari.

Best I can guess, their website builder is goofing the DOM tags in such a way that nothing can read it to make a correct print file.  Check out my site (NoSoCoAir.net) and see a print or print preview.

Anyone else experience this and find a script work around?  I'd very much appreciate any assistance.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with software development or computer programming.

Comment: I'm asking for a script recommendation.  That is my programming angle.